# display value in dropdown

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dropdown

Update

there is some values in ddl_category when i select value these values against this "-" is display in ddl_item .. so i want the selected value in ddl_item which i select in ddl_Cateogry ...

i do this both on ddl_Cateogry and ddl_item but nothing works

```
Protected Sub ddl_Item_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddl_Item.SelectedIndexChanged
        If (ddl_Item.Text = "-") Then
            ddl_Item.Text = ddl_category.Text
        End If
    End Sub

Protected Sub ddl_cateogry_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddl_cateogry.SelectedIndexChanged
        If (ddl_Item.Text = "-") Then
            ddl_Item.Text =ddl_cateogry.Text
        End If

        GetItem()
        ddl_cateogry.Visible = True
        lbt_ter2.Visible = True
        ddl_Item.Visible = True
        lbt_tie.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: Can  edit  your post with part of your code  ?

Comment: @AfnanAhmad check update

Comment: you got to provide some sample values and/or explain better. I personally stopped understanding description right after *...if i select abc value from sub-cateogory...*.

Comment: you need more info? @T.S.

Comment: I would say like this... I don't need anything. But if you want to get an answer, you need to provide better explanation.

Comment: @T.S. ok check update...

Comment: Is this win forms or asp.net?

Comment: vb.net.. web application

Comment: In this case more efficient would be to do these combo boxes in javascript. But I can [later] show the way to do it in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

your question is about winforms and not asp.net as you tagged.
if i understood your question correctly, you can achieve that result by using the `TextChanged` event of ddl_Item combobox:

```
Protected Sub ddl_Item_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddl_Item.TextChanged
    If (ddl_Item.Text = "-") Then
        ddl_Item.Text = ddl_subcategory.Text
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: i do this... but value not visible.. i mean if i select value from sub-category suppose i select fruits from sub-cateogry then if against fruits value display "-" in item then i want to get fruits value from sub-cateogry in item instead of "-"

Comment: Did you define that textchanged event on ddl_Item combobox?

Comment: sorry i did not get you ??

Comment: in simple words, did you replaces `Protected Sub ddl_subcategory_SelectedIndexChanged` with `Protected Sub ddl_Item_TextChanged` ?

Comment: oh. but whey replace whereas i want to do this on ddl_subcategory.. when any value select from subcategory then against these values in ddl_item values is displayed

Comment: because the text event will of ddl_item combobox will monitor the "-" value (after the change has beem done and immediately will replace it with the current value of ddl_subcategory. try and see if it works.

Comment: hello......... i try this Protected Sub ddl_Item_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddl_Item.SelectedIndexChanged
        If (ddl_Item.Text = "-") Then  
            ddl_Item.Text = ddl_subcategory.Text
        End If
    End Sub................. on item dropdown event but this is not working

Comment: maybe "-" has white space (meaning "-" is something like "   -   ") try to replace the line `If (ddl_Item.Text = "-") Then` to `(If ddl_Item.Text.Containes("-")) Then`

Comment: can not solve.. my sp on ddl_cateogry look like this ...... select 0 Itemid, '-' ItemDesc 
  union all
  select ci.Itemid, ci.Description ItemDesc 
  from  Item ci where ci.Typeid=@Typeid....this sp execute on GetItem()

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the best way to do something like this is to do it in javascript/JSON on the client, so you don't have to do post back. Also can be done with jquery/AJAX but my example will show how to do it with regular asp.net postback. This is pseudo code.

```
' first you need a class that can help you to retrieve the lists for your drop downs
' you need a drop down item class. You will load 3 lists of them
class DropdownItem
    Public Property Group as String
    Public Property Display as String
    Public Property Value as String
end class
' wrap all into one item
class CacheWrapper
    Public Property Categories as List(Of DropdownItem)
    Public Property SubCategories as List(Of DropdownItem)
    Public Property Items as List(Of DropdownItem)
end class
' enum to distinct load
public enum DDLType
    Category = 1
    SubCategory = 2
    Item = 3
end enum

class DropDownLoader

    dim _lock as new Object()
    constant _cacheKey as string = "guid"


    public shared sub LoadDropDown(ddl as DropdownList, group as string, type as DDLType)
         dim wrapper as CacheWrapper = httpcontext.current.cache.get(_cacheKey)
         if wrapper is Nothing then
             SyncLock lockobject  
                 wrapper = httpcontext.current.cache.get(_cacheKey) 
                 if wrapper is Nothing then
                     LoadAndCacheLists()
                     wrapper = httpcontext.current.cache.get(_cacheKey) 
                 end if
             End SyncLock  
         end if

         ' here you actually load drop down based on request
         ddl.Items.clear()
         select case type
             case DDLType.Category
                 wrapper.Categories.forEach(sub(i) ddl.Items.Add(i.display, i.Value))
             case DDLType.SubCategory
                 wrapper.SubCategories.Where(function(i) i.Group = group).ToList().forEach(sub(i) ddl.Items.Add(i.display, i.Value))
             case DDLType.Item
                 wrapper.Items.Where(function(i) i.Group = group).ToList().forEach(sub(i) ddl.Items.Add(i.display, i.Value))
         end select

    end sub

    private shared sub LoadAndCacheLists
        ' here you load from db you Category, subcategory and items and load them into lists.
        ' you set them into CacheWrapper and do something like this using your favorite cache - http, runtime, nCache, enterprise library, etc.
        httpcontext.cache.add(_cacheKey, myCacheWrapper)

        ' for this excercise, I do manual ++!! ONLY to show how structure should look
        dim catList As new List(Of DropdownItem)() ' note - no group here 
        catList.add(new DropdownItem() With { .Display = "Cat 1", .Value = "Cat1Id" })
        catList.add(new DropdownItem() With { .Display = "Cat 2", .Value = "Cat2Id" })

        dim subcatList As new List(Of DropdownItem)() 
        subcatList.add(new DropdownItem() With { .Group = "Cat1Id" .Display = "Sub Cat 1", .Value = "SubCat1Id" })
        catList.add(new DropdownItem() With { .Group = "Cat1Id" .Display = "Sub Cat 2", .Value = "SubCat2Id" })
        catList.add(new DropdownItem() With { .Group = "Cat2Id" .Display = "Sub Cat 3", .Value = "SubCat3Id" })
        catList.add(new DropdownItem() With { .Group = "Cat2Id" .Display = "Sub Cat 4", .Value = "SubCat4Id" })

        dim itemList As new List(Of DropdownItem)() 
        itemList.add(new DropdownItem() With { .Group = "SubCat1Id" .Display = "Item 1", .Value = "Item1Id" })
        itemList.add(new DropdownItem() With { .Group = "SubCat1Id" .Display = "Item 2", .Value = "Item2Id" })
        itemList.add(new DropdownItem() With { .Group = "SubCat2Id" .Display = "Item 3", .Value = "Item3Id" })
        itemList.add(new DropdownItem() With { .Group = "SubCat2Id" .Display = "Item 4", .Value = "Item4Id" })
        itemList.add(new DropdownItem() With { .Group = "SubCat4Id" .Display = "Item 5", .Value = "Item5Id" })
        itemList.add(new DropdownItem() With { .Group = "SubCat4Id" .Display = "Item 6", .Value = "Item6Id" })
        itemList.add(new DropdownItem() With { .Group = "SubCat3Id" .Display = "Item 7", .Value = "Item7Id" })
        itemList.add(new DropdownItem() With { .Group = "SubCat3Id" .Display = "Item 8", .Value = "Item8Id" })
    end sub
end class


' With all above in place, all you have to do is put a little code into your `SelectedIndexChanged` handlers

sub form_load 'page_load?

    ' here you set category
    DropDownLoader.LoadDropdown(ddlCategory, nothing, DDLType.category)
end sub

sub ddlCategory_SelectedIndexChanged

    DropDownLoader.LoadDropdown(ddlSubCategory, ddlCategory.SelectedValue, DDLType.Subcategory)
    ddlItems.Items.Clear()
end sub

sub ddlSubCategory_SelectedIndexChanged

    DropDownLoader.LoadDropdown(ddlItems, ddlSubCategory.SelectedValue, DDLType.Items)

end sub

sub ddlItems_SelectedIndexChanged

    ' here you do your business

end sub
```

Now, this is general approach, you may need few if-then, or even introduce a variable like `_indexChangedbyProgram` to bypass all or some code in `SelectedIndexChanged`. If you have an "empty item", then you need logic to bypass and clear next ddl. You need to tune this. But the approach is there.

Comment: so com;licateddddd

Comment: @cooluser Not really. this is just regular pattern of solving the issue you have in hand. Quote: *"The reason to introduce complexity into a system is to achieve simplicity of extending it."* Or you can replace *extending* with *maintaining*. If tomorrow, lets say, you need to introduce 4th drop down, your system can support it easily.